# How to view SSL-certificate details in Firefox mobile

Tags: firefox, android, ssl-certificate

In the desktop versions of Firefox it's possible to view details of a sites SSL-certificate by clicking on the lock symbol and then navigating through the popup.

Is there a way of viewing the certificate infos on Firefox mobile on android?

Solutions with addons are also OK.

Comment: This answer on Stackoverflow suggests it is at least possible with addons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983401/how-can-i-get-the-ssl-certificate-info-for-the-current-page-in-a-firefox-add-o

Answer (score 8):

They have a ticket open for it:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1612336

You can sign in and vote for it and the feature might be added sooner.

Comment: No, this ticket is for Firefox Desktop, not mobile

Comment: @phil294 think it was miss-filed, or perhaps the android version uses some desktop code. The title does say it's regarding "mobile", but I added a question to follow up and confirm.

Comment: oops, looks like you're right! thank you

Answer (score 5):

Unlike Google Chrome mobile app, Firefox is not allowing users to see SSL Certificate details. Strange! Also,I never found any plugin that can be merged with Firefox app to see in-depth details. Chrome is the best at its business.